# Compare a variable to all the variables from a Lua table?

Tags: lua

I am a new Lua user, and I have some questions regarding comparing variables to multiple values from a table.

So, let's start.

I have a variable named 'PLATE' that is equal to "AAA 111" .

I also have a table names 'VEHICLES' that has multiple values similar to PLATE, for example: AAA 333, AAA 222, AAA 111.

I use a script to check if PLATE is equal to value from the table. Here is the script:

```
for i = 1, #Vehicles, 1 do

  if PLATE == Vehicles[i].plate then 
    -- do action
  elseif PLATE ~= Vehicles[i].plate then
    -- do  2 action
  end
end
```

Because AAA 111 has the index 3, it first checks index 1 and index 2, and runs the second action. However, I don't want this to happen. I wan't to first check all the values, from the table, and if **NONE** of them is AAA 111 to run the second action. Is there a way I can to that ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a table contains an element in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282444/how-to-check-if-a-table-contains-an-element-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a Lua [Table-as-Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282444/how-to-check-if-a-table-contains-an-element-in-lua).

```
plates = {}

function addToSet(set, key) --see the linked answer for more functions like this
    set[key] = true
end

function setContains(set, key)
    return set[key] ~= nil
end

function checkPlate(PLATE)
  if setContains(plates, PLATE) then
    print("One of the plates is", PLATE)
  else
    print("There is no plate", PLATE)
  end
end

addToSet(plates, "AAA 111")
addToSet(plates, "AAA 123")

local PLATE = "AAA 123"
checkPlate(PLATE)

PLATE = "AAA 456"
checkPlate(PLATE)
```

OUTPUT:

```
One of the plates is    AAA 123
There is no plate   AAA 456
```

This is also much more efficient than looping, and if you wanted to change the plates table to include more information about plates, using plates as dictionary keys, i.e:

```
plates = {
    ["AAA 123"] = {
          ["registered"] = {'1/2/3'}
    }
}
```

It would still work with minor modifications to the addToSet function.