# Verifying and Converting values in a table of tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

For programmatic reasons, I have a table that looks like the following (note that this is for informational purposes only, please disregard how silly the premise of storing an employee database this way would actually be):

```lua
employees =
 {
  john=
   {
    name="john",
    title="Phone Service Representative III",
    salary=17,
    differential=false,
    sched=
     {
      mon={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      tue={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      wed={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      thurs={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      fri={8,"9am-5:30pm"}
     }
   },
  jack=
   {
    name="jack",
    title="Phone Service Representative II",
    salary=15.50,
    differential=false,
    sched=
     {
      mon={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      tue={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      wed={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      thurs={8,"9am-5:30pm"},
      fri={8,"9am-5:30pm"}
     }
   },
  jane=
   {
    name="jane",
    title="Phone Service Representative I",
    salary=14.25,
    differential=true,
    sched=
     {
      mon={8,"9pm-5:30am"},
      tue={8,"9pm-5:30am"},
      wed={8,"9pm-5:30am"},
      thurs={8,"9pm-5:30am"},
      fri={8,"9pm-5:30am"}
     }
   }
 }
```

I have a need to be able to call for, for example, `employees.john.salary` to get a value of `17` to return.

I am running into trouble, however, when I try to write a function to call for a value within one of the entries.

Eventually, I hope to be able to have a separate set of functions that accepts user input, but only if the input is a valid employee, then stores the title associated with the inputted name to be called at a later time with an output of `"The "..name.title.." earns "..name.salary.." an hour. \nTheir schedule is as follows: "` but I can work out the logic and syntaxes for all of that later, once I understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I tried using a for loop to iterate through looking for values, but wasn't able to get anything I was expecting.

```lua
function employees.isemployee(testName)
  local verified=false
  for k,v in ipairs(employees) do
   if v[name]==(testName:lower()) then
     verified=true
   end
  end
  return verified
end
```

doing a `print(employees.isemployee(jane))` returns false, as does `print(employees.isemployee("jane"))`.

I've also tried swapping out `ipairs` for `pairs` and `spairs`, and redoing the loop to:

```lua
for testName,v in ipairs(employees) do
  local verified=false
  if v[name]==(testName:lower()) then
...
```

and to

```lua
for k,v in ipairs(employees) do
  if k[name]==(testName:lower()) then
...
```

and included a `print(v.name)` in the loop to see what would come out, but all that got me was `jackjane`.

I was trying to write a function for this rather than using a `table.contains()` function so that `employees.isemployee(jack)` can return true, but `employees.isemployee("Phone Service Representative II")` returns false, and vice-versa for a theoretical `istitle()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In `print(employees.isemployee(jane))`, `jane` is recognized as a global variable whose value is `nil`. Since tables cannot have a `nil` key, your function correctly returns `false`. `name` in `v[name]` has the same problem. To access the real `'name'` key, use either `v.name` or `v['name']`. [`ipairs()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) is used to iterate over array-like tables. What you want is [`pairs()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs).

However, fixing these alone won't be enough. We will come back to this later.

Since you already have a hashtable, checking whether it contains a given key does not require iterating over it. Instead, [use a `~= nil` check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282444):

```lua
function employees.isemployee(testName)
  return employees[testName:lower()] ~= nil
end
```

This function should be used with a string as the only argument, since [`:lower()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.lower) is a method of the `string` "class":

```lua
print(employees.isemployee('jane'))  -- true
```

Do note that, since this `employees.isemployee()` function is also a member of the table, `employees.isemployee('isemployee')` returns `true`. `pairs()`, if used, will also encounter it and give `v` this as a value. Functions, however, are not tables and therefore trying to access their `.name` will result in an ugly error.

Comment: So, to make sure I'm understanding, if I need to check whether a title is valid, I'd use something like

```lua
function employees.istitle(testTitle)
 local isTitle = false
 for _,v in pairs(employees) do
  if v['title']==(testTitle:lower()) then
   isTitle=true
  end
 end
return isTitle
end
```

Comment: @AerotanLightpaw You need to check for `v`'s type as well: `if type(v) ~= 'function' and v.title == testTitle:lower() then ... end`.

Comment: Also, your titles as given in the table have uppercase letters. This makes `:lower()` unnecessary and incorrect.